# How to convert html content to pdf in flutter (cannot support flutter_html_to_pdf package flutter web)

Tags: html, flutter, dart, pdf, html-to-pdf

How to convert html content to pdf in flutter
not support flutter_html_to_pdf package flutter web

i have html content like this:

content: `<p>sample text</p><p><b>sample text</b></p><p><i><b>sample text</b></i><br></p>`

I want to convert this content to pdf output with flutter web, how can I do it?
help please!

i try flutter_html_to_pdf package its work for mobile but cannot support flutter web

Answer (score 0):

@Fevzettin AYDIN. Please review the `pdf` package, which makes it easier to convert HTML to PDF and guarantees Flutter web compatibility. Use the `flutter_pdfview` package to display the generated PDF on your Flutter web application. I hope this answer satisfies your requirements.